# How to make responsive cards like in spotify playlisy

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design, responsive

I want to create the same layout as on this page https://open.spotify.com/genre/made-for-x. How to want the playlist elements to shrink until they reach 100px and then to wrap and when the window is expanding to grow until they reach 200px and then to unwrap.

Comment: You should use `css media queries` for wrapping and unwrapping. To set limit for width you should use `max-width` and `min-width`. Google responsive design using css media queries and you will find usefull articles.

Answer (score 2):

**All you need to achieve this layout is [CSS Grid](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). You don’t need media queries.**

CSS Grid has this awesome property [`grid-template-columns`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) which lets you define a fixed or dynamic number of columns.

Use [`repeat()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat()) with a value of `auto-fit` inside of `grid-template-columns` to say you want as many columns as will fit into the grid container.

Use `minmax(100px, max-content)` to say that your grid columns should be at least `100px`, but never more than the `max-content` size of the elements inside the grid.

Then, set `max-width: 200px` on your image elements, which will effectively determine that `max-content` size, because the images are sitting inside the grid.

Here’s a working example:

```css
:root {
  background-color: #111;
}

body {
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, max-content));
  gap: 24px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #333;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.playlist-image {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid-container">
  <li class="grid-item">
    <img
      class="playlist-image"
      src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/400"
      alt="Doggy"
    />
    <h3 class="playlist-name">Discover Weekly</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="grid-item">
    <img
      class="playlist-image"
      src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/400"
      alt="Doggy"
    />
    <h3 class="playlist-name">Daily Mix 1</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="grid-item">
    <img
      class="playlist-image"
      src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/400"
      alt="Doggy"
    />
    <h3 class="playlist-name">Daily Mix 2</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="grid-item">
    <img
      class="playlist-image"
      src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/400"
      alt="Doggy"
    />
    <h3 class="playlist-name">Release Radar</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="grid-item">
    <img
      class="playlist-image"
      src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/400"
      alt="Doggy"
    />
    <h3 class="playlist-name">Family Mix</h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create specific css for each screen size using @media.
Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@media to learn how to use them.